# Difference between cloning and pulling in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Clone and pull, these operations
both are similar in functioning, so does using clone instead of pull make any sense?
I mean why should I use clone if it is possible to achieve same thing by pulling an existing repo.

---

A team working on some application and later a new user say user2 allotted to that application by company then cloning existing repo or pulling existing repo for new entry(user2), which 1 is better? comparison b/w clone/pull

Comment: you have another question [Diff b/w CLONE/PULL in tortoise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914392/diff-b-w-clone-pull-in-tortoise) that covers similar ground. Could that be closed as a duplicate of this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you clone a repository then you are making a new copy, this can be an expensive process. Also if you only use clone then you will risk losing any local changes you may have made.

- You can think of cloning as copying a whole directory

When you pull then this just updates your repository with any changes that have been made on the parent repository, as it is just incorporating differences this will be a much more efficient process.

- You can think of pulling as just updating the files that have changed

I recommend you go though this tutorial: http://hginit.com/

Comment: Thanks Sam..but still i am confused b/w pull and clone concept..ok let make it clear i am asking you guys about initial phase...suppose User 'A' has a repo named 'Z' and later another developer( initially nothing in hand ) want to be a part of that application(user B) then then doing clone instead of pull or vice versa of existing repo(z) makes any favour to new user.

Comment: But user 'B' must either clone repository or copy the directory and then pull, otherwise he has nothing. It is better to do a clone because then the link between repositories is preserved. Weather he clones from 'A' or 'Z' depends on your workflow requirements.

Comment: Yup i agree thanks Sam. I want to share what i felt/found 1.hgrc(confi file) automatically filled with default path,where you can pull or push without manually specifying path for it...2.need to upd8 working dir. at first pull...3.cloning is speedy when done in locak disk and cheaper with disk space.

Answer (score 7):

**Pulling** means that you already have a local repository, and you pull in just the newest changes from the remote repository that are not in your local repository yet.

But if you don't have a local repository yet, **cloning** creates a new one, pulls *everything* from the remote repository into your new local repository and updates your working copy to the newest version.
This is the easiest way to start if you join a new project - you need to get all the code once in the beginning.

You can also do the steps for cloning manually, which has the exact same effect (but just doing `hg clone https://url_to_remote` is easier):

- create a new folder on local machine
- create an empty repository in the folder (`hg init`)
- pull everything from the remote repository (`hg pull https://url_to_remote`)
- update your working copy (`hg update`)

Comment: Christian i was asking about adv of one over other. If you don't have a local repo then pull/clone creates an identical copy of existing repo...i.e local repo for you

Comment: @Kannas: There are no advantages/disadvantages, pulling and cloning are just two different things for two different situations. If you don't have a local repository, then clone. If you have a local repository, then pull to get the newest changes. That's it.

Comment: Is there a "--stream" option for pull, too? TeamCity uses init + pull instead of clone and fails on our old server because Kallithea's internal WSGI server (waitress) can't be configured to a higher timeout. I would use a newer server but there is no working way to get Kallithea set up on Windows anymore...

Answer (score 1):

These 2 commands are completly different:

- **Clone** creates a *new repository*
- **Pull** updates an *existing repository*, bringing changes from another clone

First you clone a repository. After that, whenever you want to update this clone bringing the changes from another repo, you pull.

Answer (score 0):

- clone - is first "checkout" of the source
- pull - is download of server's "Head" /

Comment: I am new at Tortoise will you please explain it in detail...adv of clone over pull or vice versa